# Aceder à posição de um Transform numa lista em Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Tenho uma lista de Transform que contém os SpawnPoints que tenho dentro do jogo, gostaria de encontrar para cada um dos SpawnPoints a sua posição.

```
[SerializeField] List<Transform> spawns;
```

O problema consiste em dar Spawn aos carros se estiverem dentro dos limites da câmara, porém os SpawnPoints necessitam de estar fora para dar a ilusão que já nascem fora e não dentro. Como posso aceder à posição de cada SpawnPoint na lista?

```
IEnumerator SpawnCars()
    {
        while (OnCamera==true)//enquanto os spawns estiverem dentro do ecra
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);//esperar um segundo para spawnar
            Instantiate(car, spawns[Random.Range(0, spawns.Count)].position, Quaternion.identity, transform);//spawnar o carro na lista de spawns
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Olha, não sei se entendi a pergunta muito bem, porém se sim, eu te falaria para criar um foreach para percorrer a lista de Transform passando o position dela como parametro do instantiate.

```
    IEnumerator SpawnCars()
        {
            while (OnCamera==true)//enquanto os spawns estiverem dentro do ecra
            {
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);//esperar um segundo para spawnar
                foreach(Transform spawn in spawns){
                     Instantiate(car, spawn.position,Quaternion.identity,transform);//spawnar o carro na lista de spawns
                }
            }
       }
```